# Vuetify v-autocomplete object custom filter

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using vuetify v-autocomplete with an object, the object is a Key and Value. When the user search, the search is based on the item-text. As you can see in my example I display the object Key and Value Example {1200-Chloride Systems}.
So is it possible that when the user type the search is based on both the Key and Value of the object and not just the item-text?

```
                <v-autocomplete
                  label="Trading Partner"
                  v-model="tradingPartner"
                  :items="tradingpartners"
                  item-value="Key"
                  item-text="Value"
                  return-object
                >
                  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item }">
                    {{ item.Key }} - {{ item.Value }}
                  </template>
                  <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
                    {{ item.Key }} - {{ item.Value }}
                  </template>
                </v-autocomplete>
```

in the example below, you can see that 1200 is the key and Chloride Systems is the value.
The display is concatenating Key - Value.
If I clear the text and start typing I can search for the Name (Value), but if I type as example 1200 it finds nothing because the search is not on Key.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use custom `filter` prop which takes a function as value :

```
<v-autocomplete :filter="onFilter" ...
```

in methods:

```
methods:{
   onFilter(item, queryText, itemText){
        return item.Key.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase())
               ||  item.Value.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase())

   }
}
```